# EF many-to-many madness

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ienumerable

I have a method that updates a `ReportRecipient` object in EF.  The primitives work fine; the headache comes in when trying to manage a M2M relationship with the `RecipientGroups` objects.

Please take a look at this code:

```
    public IReportRecipient ModifyRecipientWithGroupAssignments(IEnumerable<Guid> groupIds, IReportRecipient recipient)
    {
        var entity = Context.ReportRecipients
            .Include("RecipientGroups")
            .FirstOrDefault(e => e.ReportRecipientId == recipient.ReportRecipientId)
            .FromIReportRecipient(recipient);

        var toRemove = entity.RecipientGroups
            .Where(e => !groupIds.Contains(e.GroupId))
            .ToList();

        //remove group assignments that no longer apply
        foreach (var group in toRemove)
        {
            if (group != null)
            {
                entity.RecipientGroups.Attach(group);
                entity.RecipientGroups.Remove(group);
            }
        }

        var toAdd = entity.RecipientGroups
            .Where(e => groupIds.Contains(e.GroupId))
            .ToList();

        //add new groups that weren't there before
        foreach (var group in toAdd)
        {
            if (group != null)
            {
                entity.RecipientGroups.Attach(group);
            }
        }

        return entity;
    }
```

... my problem is on the `var ToAdd...` line.  Even if I have a collection of Guids in `groupIds` that match Guids representing `RecipientGroup` objects in the database, `toAdd` always evaluates to an empty collection.  I would think the `Contains()` function would work for this scenario; can someone please explain if I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load the `RecipientGroup`s you want to add from the database (`Context.RecipientGroups` I guess), not from the collection you want to add them to (`entity.RecipientGroups` in the code sample).